# why in a bash script, "unshare -n /bin/bash; ps" : ps gives no output?

Tags: bash

So here's my script :

```
#!/bin/bash
unshare -n /bin/bash
ps
```

Why `ps` doesn't give any output when I run the script ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It *will*. It hasn't been executed yet. `unshare -n /bin/bash` is still running.

First you have to exit `bash` (`exit`, `ctrl+d`, ...)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass a command to your new shell:

```
#!/bin/bash
unshare -n /bin/bash -c ps
```